# Need to copy ACE from one user to another

Tags: active-directory, powershell

Currently I need to allow all users to have read access to two computer objects. I can accomplish this manually in the GUI but it's not practical.

I have a user that is working when I manually add it.

`(Get-Acl -Path $userstring).access | Where-Object {$_.identityreference -like '*ise-*'}`

```
ActiveDirectoryRights : ReadProperty, GenericExecute
InheritanceType       : None
ObjectType            : 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
InheritedObjectType   : 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
ObjectFlags           : None
AccessControlType     : Allow
IdentityReference     : ***************
IsInherited           : False
InheritanceFlags      : None
PropagationFlags      : None

ActiveDirectoryRights : ReadProperty, GenericExecute
InheritanceType       : None
ObjectType            : 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
InheritedObjectType   : 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
ObjectFlags           : None
AccessControlType     : Allow
IdentityReference     : ***********
IsInherited           : False
InheritanceFlags      : None
PropagationFlags      : None
```

The code I have tried is here:

```
Set-Location ad:
$distinguishedname = (get-aduser ptest).distinguishedname

$acl = (get-acl -Path $distinguishedname).access

#$acl.access #to get access right of the OU

$computer = get-adcomputer "ise-watson"

$sid = [System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier] $computer.SID

# Create a new access control entry to allow access to the OU

$identity = [System.Security.Principal.IdentityReference] $SID

$adRights = [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectoryRights] "ReadProperty, GenericExecute"

$type = [System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType] "Allow"



$inheritanceType = [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectorySecurityInheritance] "All"



$ACE = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectoryAccessRule $identity,$adRights,$type,$inheritanceType

# Add the ACE to the ACL, then set the ACL to save the changes

$acl.AddRule($ace)

Set-acl -aclobject $acl -Path $distinguishedname

This throws an error: 
Set-acl : AclObject
At line:32 char:1
+ Set-acl -aclobject $acl -Path $distinguishedname
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (System.Security...nRuleCollection:AuthorizationRuleCollection) [Set-Acl], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SetAcl_AclObject,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetAclCommand
```

Comment: That script doesn't make sense. You said you want to grant access to computer objects. So the ACL and ACE should be on those computer objects. But the script is getting the ACL from a user object. That's the opposite of what you stated.

Answer (score 1):

Why apply individual ACEs for each user?

Create a security group, grant that group access to the object in question, and the required users to the group and then you're done - and its future proofed.